# Custom (Non-OAuth) Refresh Token Implementation

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, auth-token

I'm working on an application that uses a token-based authentication system, where the user provides their username / password and receives a token in return (the token gets saved to the database as well). Then subsequent requests will include this token as a custom header and we can use this to identify the user. This all works fine.

Right now if the user doesn't login for 3 days, we expire the token. I was reading a little about refresh tokens in OAuth and I was wondering if I could somehow implement something similar. i.e. when providing the auth token, I also provide a refresh token which can be used later to request a new auth token. In terms of security though, it seems quite similar to just never expiring the user's auth token in the first place. Should I be sending additional information with the refresh token to validate the user?

Answer (score -1):

In OAuth2, the resource server and authorization server are often not the same.

The refresh token is sent back to the client when the access token is issued and when the token is refreshed. **The client needs to authenticate itself (using client id and client secret) to use the refresh token**. The resource server never sees the refresh token.

Also, access tokens are not stored at the server side as they have a limited lifetime. Refresh tokens are stored and can therefore be revoked.